# How do I make the data persistent in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

So, this is my View Model

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import Alamofire


class AllStatsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isLoading: Bool = true
    @Published var stats = [CountryStats]()

    func fetchGlobalStats() {
        let request = AF.request("https://projectcovid.deadpool.wtf/all")
       request.responseDecodable(of: AllCountryStats.self) { (response) in
         guard let globalStats = response.value else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.stats = globalStats.data
        }

        self.isLoading = false
       }
    }
}
```

And this is my view where I subscribe to change:

```
struct CardView: View {
    @ObservedObject var allStatsVM = AllStatsViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if self.allStatsVM.stats.count > 0 {
                Text(self.allStatsVM.stats[0].country)
            } else {
                Text("data loading")
            }   

        }


        .onAppear {
            self.allStatsVM.fetchGlobalStats()
        }
    }

}
```

So, when I open the app for the first time, I get the data and then when I go home and reopen the app, all I can see is data loading.

Is there a way to persist data? I know @State helps but, I'm a beginner in SwiftUI and not sure how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every time you open CardView you create a new:

```
@ObservedObject var allStatsVM = AllStatsViewModel()
```

what you probably want is to create that in the home view, and pass in the ObservedObject from the home view to the CarView, where you declare:

```
@ObservedObject var allStatsVM: AllStatsViewModel
```

The data will then persist, and when CardView appear again it will show it.